# Partial Refresh of repeat control/pager not working with Bootstrap tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I noticed that a repeat control with a pager under a Bootstrap tab causes the complete content under a tab to disappear when I select the pager.

Does anybody know the cause of this?

If I navigate to another tab and navigate back to the tab with the repeat control I see that the pager did its work and the state of the repeat control is correct (next document displayed) but why is it destroying the display/html?

I do not see any error in the web browser console.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:
viewScope.myTest = 
       [["Val_1_1", "Val_1_2"], ["Val_2_1", "Val_2_2"], ["Val_3_1", "Val_3_2"]];}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <div>
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="">
                <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#repeat" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    Repeat</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="home">...</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="repeat">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Column 1</th>
                            <th>Column 2</th>                           
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <xp:repeat id="rptDecisions" rows="1" var="row"
                            indexVar="idx" value="#{viewScope.myTest}">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xp:text value="#{row[0]}" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xp:text value="#{row[1]}" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xp:repeat>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next" id="pager1" for="rptDecisions"
                    partialRefresh="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</xp:view>
```

Update:

it looks like the ID's generated by XPages does not seem to work so fine with the Bootstrap tabs anchors?

```
<div>
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <xp:link escape="true" text="Repeat" id="link2">
                    <xp:this.attrs>
                        <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="tab" />
                        <xp:attr name="role" value="tab" />
                    </xp:this.attrs>
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"#" + getComponent("repeat").getClientId(facesContext)}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:link>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab"
                    data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">home</div>
            <xp:div role="tabpanel" styleClass="tab-pane" id="repeat">
                repeat
            </xp:div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">messages</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is: you aren't providing XSP with a "handle" it can hook up to in order to perform the partial refresh without "destroying" your block. For conversation's sake, your same code would work if you changed the page property to `partialRefresh="false"` because the whole page would be re-evaluated with no need for specific container block. Anyway...

You transform

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="repeat">
```

into

```
<xp:div id="commonContainer" role="tabpanel" styleClass="tab-pane fade">
```

and things will start working.

One other important thing to keep in mind is that both the repeater and the pager must share the common container that will be refreshed.

**EDIT**

I suggest you to look into the **Bootstrap4XPages** and `<xp:tabbedPanel>` project that lightens the understanding and efforts you have to put forth to reach your goal. As it is now there are many more things to consider and leaving it aside might bite you again down the road.

Still, a quick fix to the above code would simply be the one of restructuring the code to honor the rule I mentioned before.

```
<div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="home">...</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="repeat">

            <xp:div id="thisCommonContainerImTalkingAbout">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Column 1</th>
                            <th>Column 2</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <xp:repeat id="rptDecisions" rows="1" var="row"
                        value="#{viewScope.myTest}" themeId="List.Table">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xp:text value="#{row[0]}" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xp:text value="#{row[1]}" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xp:repeat>
                </table>

                <xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next" id="pager1" for="rptDecisions"
                    partialRefresh="true" />
            </xp:div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: question: if I change the div into an xp:div the ID becomes dynamic too then so the reference to open it should also be that then? how should I do this?

Comment: i have problems with the tabs ad referring to xpages generated id's. I used getComponent("repeat").getClientId(facesContext) to get the client ID (in the browser). in the source it looks OK but it does not work.

Comment: if I alter the dom (removing the dynamic id's to static ids (e.g. id=repeater) the tabs work :-(

Comment: Where do you need to reference the XSP generated client id? Can you provide more insight regarding your code? However this needs goes beyond the scope of the question you asked.

Comment: I guess I need the reference in the nav-tabs anchor links? e.g. <li role="presentation">
    <xp:link escape="true" text="Repeat" id="link2">
     <xp:this.attrs>
      <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="tab" />
      <xp:attr name="role" value="tab" />
     </xp:this.attrs>
     <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"#" + getComponent("repeat").getClientId(facesContext)}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:link>
   </li>

Comment: hi Shillem, I got it to work now thanks to your code. Thank you for helping me out!